# Does Tweepy Streaming API work on Google App Engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, tweepy

I'm trying to use the Tweepy Library to follow a user. This means using the Streaming API. I'm using the Google App Engine SDK release: "1.9.40". Everything works on my Dev server but when I deploy to Production, it stops working. I don't get an error.

Basically what is happening is - the code I have in on_status is not being triggered. I added a checkpoint and it is not being printed to the log file. But on Dev, it is being triggered.

```
def on_status(self, status):
    decoded = json.loads(status)
    logger.info(decoded) # Checkpoint
```

I saw some older posts (2013...) that said streaming is not supported on App Engine but I just want to confirm if that is still the case in 2016. And if it is not supported, how come it works on the Dev env? Finally, what are my alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: I am very unhappy about it too, but I confirmed with Google a few months ago that streaming is not supported. And there have been no announcements since then.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine does not support streaming. You can use a Compute Engine instance instead.

Comment: If streaming is not supported, do you know why it works on Development Server? I was under the impression that Development Server mimics Production and so anything not supported in Production should not work in Development. Or is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: It *tries* to emulate the production, but it's not always possible.